# React Native app crashing on startup in android Release mode

Tags: android, react-native

I tried every solution I could find online, nothing seems to work, including StackOverflow and ChatGPT.  My react Native app works fine in debug mode, but crashes on startup in release mode, targetSDK : 33.

Here is relevant code :
Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>

<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
tools:targetApi="s" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:targetApi="33"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

build.gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4"

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

graddle-wrapper.properties :

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "home_controller",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.14",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^7.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "@remobile/react-native-toast": "^1.0.7",
    "ansi-styles": "^6.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "date-fns-tz": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "^14.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "i18next": "^22.4.14",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^12.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.68.4",
    "react-native-bluetooth-serial": "^1.0.0-rc1",
    "react-native-color-picker": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "5.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.10.3",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^15.0.1",
    "react-native-modals": "^0.22.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "3.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.3.1",
    "react-native-wheel-color-picker": "^1.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.6",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I also tried importing 'react-native-gesture-handler' at the top of index.js, no effect.  At this point I am guessing a library or package version is wrong or outdated, but there is no error message, so it's hard to tell, anyone seen this before?

there is however an ADB error log :

```
09-08 11:17:06.288 14054 14054 E home_controller: Not starting debugger 
since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
09-08 11:17:06.401 14054 14080 E home_controller: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
```